# send json response to client when i activated raspberry gpio

Tags: python, tornado

I have a face detection project that i want to activate one of the raspberry pi gpio ports when a face is detected, which I can do without any problems.
Now I want to have an API that when a port is activated, the true response as json is sent to the client. I use the tornado web server.

```
import cv2
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)    



cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    if  len(faces)>0:
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(18 ,GPIO.HIGH)
    else:    
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)



    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows(
```

)

this is my tornado code:

```
import face_detection
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import json
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        '''face detection code'''

        self.write(json.dumps({'response':True}))

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

but i can't to send json response to client.wahts wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending the correct header. For a JSON response you need to send the `Content-Type` header to tell the client know that this is a JSON response, like this: `Content-Type: application/json`.

You've two options now:

**1. Give `self.write` the raw dict instead of json data**

If you give `self.write` a dictionary, it will automatically convert it to JSON and set the appropirate `Content-Type` header. You won't have to worry about that.

```
self.write({'reponse': True}) # pass the dict, not JSON
```

---

**2. OR set the header yourself**

If you want to send the json manually, you can set the header yourself, like this:

```
self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
self.write(json.dumps({'response': True}))
```